# Bluetooth pairing not working with "unknown sources" .apk

Tags: android, bluetooth, apk, epson

I'm using the android Epson SDK for printing within my app. Everything works when running out of Android Studio on the test devices.

The app is sent out as a signed .apk through email for distribution.

But when pairing is attempted again an unknown error is shown.

```
ERR_FAILURE
```

Epson SDK: ERR_FAILURE = An unspecified error occurred.

My question is, do "unknown sources" apps lose permissions?

I've gone over the SKD but cannot find anything. Has anyone distributed an app, where "unknown sources" had to be enabled, and noticed any issues?

Thanks

UPDATE:

The debug_unalinged.apk works.

I understand that:

> Aligned apk applications have all their uncompressed data aligned to 4-byte boundaries, allowing it to be accessed directly through some of the android APIs. Benefit of alignment is supposedly less memory overhead when running the app.

How can this affect a Bluetooth connection to a printer?